# seeking debugging help ("why isn't the HTML5 video play at IE?")

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm having problem playing the video at Internet explorer .
After I close the pop-up video, and want to replay it again, it wouldn't work.
Error of unsupported type or invalid file path. Do you know why it does not play at IE? Thank you.

```
        <!--  === ===  BODY COPY  === ===  -->
  <h2>Watch now to investigate.</h2>
 <div id="popUpVideoBackground"></div>
 <div id="popUpVideoContainer">
 <div id="videoCaption"></div>
<h4 id="videoTime"></h4>
<div><a href="javascript:closePopUpVideo()"><img id="closeIcon"   src="images/favicons/close_icon.png" /></a> <video id="popUpVideo" width="640" height="480" controls="controls"><source src="" type="video/mp4" /> </video>  
</div>
</div>
<!--  === ===  Video 1  === ===  -->
<div class="imgContainer"> 
<a class="ImageLink" href="javascript:playTrailer('http://cdn.sciex.com/BLT_Tease_pt1.mp4','Mission-X underway Part 1')">
<img class="overlayIcon" src="images/favicons/playBtn_40x36.jpg" /> 
<img class="videoImage" src="Images/campaigns/food/BLTteaser1_200x140.jpg" />   
 </a> </div>
 <div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


    function playTrailer(video, title) { 
      document.getElementById("videoCaption").innerHTML=title;
      document.getElementById("popUpVideoBackground").style.display="inline";
      document.getElementById("popUpVideo").style.display="inline";
      document.getElementById("closeIcon").style.display="inline";
      document.getElementById("popUpVideoContainer").style.display="inline";
      document.getElementById("popUpVideo").setAttribute('src',video);
      document.getElementById("popUpVideo").setAttribute('type',"video/mp4");
      document.getElementById("popUpVideo").load();
      document.getElementById("popUpVideo").play();

       if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 ) 
       {
         document.getElementById("popUpVideo").style.marginTop="0px"; 
         document.getElementById("popUpVideo").style.height="460px";
         document.getElementById("popUpVideoContainer").style.height="550px";
       }

        if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) ||  (!!document.documentMode == true )) //IF IE > 10
       {               
             document.getElementById("popUpVideo").style.marginTop="100px"; 
             document.getElementById("popUpVideo").style.height="480px"; 
             document.getElementById("popUpVideoContainer").style.height="630px" ;
       }
    }
    function closePopUpVideo(){
        document.getElementById("popUpVideoBackground").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("popUpVideo").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("popUpVideoContainer").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("closeIcon").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("popUpVideo").pause();
    }
```

Comment: Which version of IE? In general though I'd recommend to not do any browser sniffing at all.

Comment: Apparently Edge doesn't respond to `MSIE` anymore. http://tinyurl.com/poj4e7c

Comment: What can I do to make the video play at MSIE?

Comment: You could give `|| (navigator.userAgent.match(Edge\/\d+))` a go...

Comment: Anyway, you'd have to include that to sniff out Edge as well but after looking into it this doesn't seem to be the main issue. That would be the MIME type disagreeing with IE. Don't have much of a clue there...

Comment: Thanks @Shikkediel please let me know if you have any more clue or suggestion.